# Cannot change the status bar color in iOS NativeScript

Tags: nativescript

I am trying to change the color text of the status bar in iOS to white. This is what I've done so far :

```
import { topmost } from "ui/frame";

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor() {

    }
    ngOnInit()
    {
        if(app.ios)
        {
            var navBar = topmost().ios.controller.navigationBar;
            navBar.barStyle = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

But this seems not to be working. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Is there anyway to achieve this ???

Comment: Same here, any solution?

Comment: If you are trying to set the statusbar color without having an actionbar in the page then your method will not work as an actionbar (aka navigationBar) is required.

Try the following instead:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57555115/how-to-change-the-status-bar-color-in-ios-without-an-actionbar-in-nativescript#57555116