# How to change the status bar color in IOS without an Actionbar in Nativescript?

Tags: nativescript

I can't work out how to change IOS's status bar in nativescript without the requirement of having an ActionBar / NavigationBar.

I've tried:

```
var navController = frame.topmost().ios.controller;
let navigationBar = navController.navigationBar;
navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Black;
```

But this totally fails when there is no ActionBar!

Answer (score 5):

This solution works!

#### Step 1:

Add the below to `app/App_Resources/iOS/Info.plist`.

```
<key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>
<string>UIStatusBarStyleLightContent</string>
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<false/>
```

It will do the following:

1. Set default color for the splash screen and app to white.
2. Allow you to change the status bar color within the app.

---

#### Step 2:

After adding that you can then use the below snippet to change the status bar style color:

```
// white status bar text
UIApplication.sharedApplication.setStatusBarStyleAnimated(UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent, true);
// black status bar text
UIApplication.sharedApplication.setStatusBarStyleAnimated(UIStatusBarStyle.Default, true);
```

---

#### Optional But Important Step 3:

If you want to change the status bar as soon as the application finishes loading (after splash screen) or when it becomes active then you'll need to set the above snippet inside a `UiApplicationDelegate` function. See link for example:

https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/application-lifecycle#ios-uiapplicationdelegate

Comment: I can't get this to work. Which version of iOS and nativescript are you using? I am on  iOS 12.4.1 and tns 6.1.0.

Comment: Where did you add Step 2...?

Answer (score 0):

@Jammer answer is correct, i was able to set the color of the status bar text using this method on Nativescript-Angular, is important to mention, you need to clear your build/cache folder (`tns platform remove ios`) to update configurations on next build every-time you update `Info.plist`, this small bug happens even on NS7+

Note: you also need `tns-platform-declarations` to avoid common typescript errors. Also remember this is just for iOS so it is required to add validations to avoid any issue on Android.